# Absolute convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{2+5nx}$, find the limit of the function and find an interval in which it is uniformly convergent.

My solution, clearly $f$ is undefined on x=$\frac{-2}{5n}$ and undefined at x=0. if x=+n or -n, $|f_n(n)-f(n)|\to o$ and $|f_n(-n)-f(-n)|\to o$ so the limit exists for x in [-n,0) and (0,n] and uniformly convergent if x=n or -n.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: @SugataAdhya it doesnt specify in the book but $\mathbb{R}$ i assume

Comment: It can't be whole of $\mathbb R$ for $f_1$ is not defined at $-\dfrac{2}{5}.$

Comment: @SugataAdhya surely you can have a function with the domain of the reals, it may be undefined in certain places but that doesn't take away from it's initial domain...

Comment: Do you mean find the limit of the sequence of functions? meaning $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)$ or do you mean $\lim_{x \to 0} f_n (x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try $[0,\infty)$ for your domain. Always start, as the problem suggests, by finding the pointwise limit. Graphing typical functions also helps.